# What does "kernel based" mean?

Tags: image-processing, algorithms, matrix, tracking, visual-tracking

In my thesis I try to explain what kernel based methods are, especially the meaning for object detection.

I know kernel based methods like [Mean- and CamShift](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/df8/tutorial_py_meanshift.html) and I know how to use them. I understand how the shift work. But: What does the kernel do, what does he describe?

I know, wikipedia have articles about kernels but I still don´t get it. :(

Q1: What could be an subset for an image?

Q2: How does the kernel project the points in an image?

Q3: Could you give me an simple example to understand kernels?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, a kernel is a function that acts as a parameter to some algorithm.

**Filtering:** For example, it's possible to call the impulse response of a filter $h[n]$ a kernel, so that it is the parameter that defines the filter operation:
$$
y[n] = h[n] * x[n].
$$

The use of the term kernel in the filtering context is [much more common in 2D filtering or image processing.](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/kernel.htm)  The link talks about the kernel being a matrix, but really it's just a sampling of the function that is the "true" kernel.

**PDF Estimation:** Kernel-based methods are often used in other contexts, too.  For example, when estimating the probability density function of a random variable, [kernel-based estimators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) are often preferable to simple histogramming.  [In that context, there are many different possible kernels.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)#Kernel_functions_in_common_use)

[image]

**Machine Learning:** Finally, another context for kernel based algorithms is in [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method).  Here, we are interested in classification of an input into one of (possibly) many classes.  Again, the kernel is a function $k(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}')$ that parametrizes the algorithm and [there are many possible selections.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method#Popular_kernels)

Comment: Nice answer +1... I'd say that in the context of PDF Kernel Methods are considered parameter free methods.

Comment: Can we think of a "kernel" to be like stencil that is used in arts and drawing?

Comment: @engr A bit of a loose analogy, but not a bad one. Yes, I that’s one way they could be thought of.